# Is there any alternative of [pSelectableRow]="rowData" that we can use?

Tags: angular, primeng

trying overriding the css but doesn't workout for me

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-selectable-row.selected.ui-state-highlight {
  //background-color: royalblue;
  background: #f0f5f9;
  border: none;
}
```

I'm not able to override the default css of pSelectableRow. It helps to make my row clickable if I remove it that functionality is getting break. So, I need the alternative of that.

Comment: check your tags!

Comment: Have you tried to use Viewencapsulation.None / moving this style to style.css? It would be better if you could make a Stackblitz example.